# Differentiation of a function with absolute value

Tags: functions, derivatives, absolute-value

If $f(x) = |x| + 3x^3$ for all real $x$, I want to calculate the value of $f′(−1)$. My answer is $8$, but the solution says it's $-7$. Any ideas?

Comment: Your answer is correct, not the 'solution'.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get the exponent right? The given solution would be correct for 
$$f(x)= |x|+3x^2.$$